# Fix thmtool spacing when using the parskip package

Tags: spacing, thmtools, parskip

While on polished documents the usual paragraph spacing is nice, in personal notes I prefer to have non-indented paragraphs separated by blank lines.
This can be easily accomplished by using the `parskip` package.

When used in conjunction with `thmtools` however, the spacing around theorem environments is completely off.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\declaretheorem{theorem}
\declaretheorem[style=remark]{remark}


\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

  \lipsum[2]
  \lipsum[2]
  \begin{theorem}
    This is cool maths.
  \end{theorem}
  \lipsum[2]
  \begin{remark}
    This is cool maths.
  \end{remark}
  \lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

I know I can define my own style and set `spaceabove=\parskip` and `spacebelow=0pt` but this has the negative side-effect of requiring to also re-specify all the other parameters even for predefined styles.
For example, `\declaretheoremstyle[spaceabove=\parskip, spacebelow=0pt]{remark}` would make `remark`s look like theorem, whereas without the `\declaretheoremstyle` the name is in italics.

I have a solution that I am posting as an answer which I am not completely satisfied with.

The question is: can one patch `thmtools` properly so it picks up the `\parskip`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An unsatisfactory solution is to use the `preheadhook` option to insert some vertical space.
For added convenience, the hook can be installed via a custom `parskip` key:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{thmtools}
%%%%%% Here we define the parskip key
\makeatletter
\define@key{thmdef}{parskip}[]{\thmt@trytwice{}{\addtotheorempreheadhook[\thmt@envname]{\vspace{\parskip}}}}

\def\thmt@proof@preheadhook{\vspace{-\parskip}}
\makeatother

%%%%%% Here we use it to add the vertical space
\declaretheorem[parskip]{theorem}
\declaretheorem[style=remark,parskip]{remark}


\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

  \lipsum[2]
  \lipsum[2]
  \begin{theorem}
    This is cool maths.
  \end{theorem}
  \lipsum[2]
  \begin{remark}
    This is cool maths.
  \end{remark}
  \lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```